# Перемещение данных между lua и c++

Tags: c++, c, lua

Собственно ситуация такая: у меня есть библиотека для `lua` (написана на `c++`) которая предоставляет доступ к некоему объекту из `c++` кода (допустим, вектору). При этом этот объект аллоцирует память в куче, а сам объект я размещаю в `userdata` `lua`, примерно так:

```cpp
std::vector<int> *buf = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int> *>(lua_newuserdata(state, sizeof(std::vector<int>)));
new (buf) std::vector<int>(10);
```

Помните: то, что выше - это вызов `C++` из `Lua`! Когда я вызываю из `C++`(!) скрипт на `lua`, который возвращает мне подобный объект (`userdata` с размещенным в нем `std::vector`) в с++ я произвожу нечто подобное:

```cpp
std::vector<int> out;
auto *vec = reinterpret_cast<std::vector<int>*>lua_touserdata(state, -1));
if (vec) {
  out = std::move(*out);
}
```

Как видите, я использую `move` чтобы избежать ненужного копирования. Так вот, все вроде работало прекрастно, пока не потребовалось собрать прилагу под `windows`. В результате я начал получать `segmentation fault` из-за того, что `out` был поврежден. Как-будто, несмотря на `move` данные выделенные в куче были освобождены по выходу из скрипта. Собственно вопрос: насколько безопасно перемещать таким образом данные?

PS `lua-5.1.5`

PSS также забыл упомянуть, что для избежания утечек памяти объекту в `lua` был добавлен метод `__gc` в котором просто вызывается деструктор условного вектора. Он отрабатывает по завершению всего скрипта

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/101828/discussion-on-question-by-andrej-levkovitch----lua--c).